# Prime divisors of the norm of the first coefficient of an elliptic newform at width-1 cusps.

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve of conductor $N$ and let $f$ be its newform.
Suppose $p \geq 5$ is a prime such that $p^2 \mid N$. We assume $f$ is $p$-minimal, which is equivalent to that the reduction type of $E$ at $p$ is potentially good, or that the local representation $\pi_{f,p}$ is supercuspidal. 
Let $\alpha = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 &0 \\ N/p &1 \end{matrix}\right]$ and write $f|[\alpha](q) = \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n q^n$. Note that $a_1 \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p) = K$, so we can put $T = Norm_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(a_1)$. It turns out that $a_1$, and hence the rational number $T$, are determined by the representation $\pi_{f,p}$, which, in turn, is determined by a character of $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^{\times}$ whose order is in the set $\{3,4,6\} \cap \{a \in \mathbb{Z}: a \mbox{  divides } p+1\}$ (For proof of these claims, see [this paper](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/francois.brunault/recherche/ephi.pdf) by @François Brunault).

I computed $T$ in various cases and found that its prime factors  always consist of  $p$  and primes that are $\pm1$ mod $p$. The table of these prime divisors for $5 \leq p \leq 300$ can be found [here](https://github.com/haochenuw/qexpansion/blob/master/T_(p%20in%205-300).txt).

My question is: is this always the case? i.e., is it true that for every $p \geq 5$ and every possible order of the character, we have the facotrization $T = p^k \prod q_i^{k_i}$, where $q_i \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}$? Any idea/suggestion on whether this claim holds, or on how to go about proving it, will be appreciated!